# AWS: How to list all cloudwatch metric namespaces

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get the list of available CloudWatch metric namespaces, later I will make use of them to get metrics.

Comment: I want a similar response to the one below via SDK.

Comment: Do you want to do from sdk?

Comment: [Getting metrics from CloudWatch - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-get-metrics.html)

Comment: here we are passing the namespace whereas I first want to list all the available metric namespaces under cloud watch via SDK

Comment: how would you like to get, either using SDK or cli based?

Comment: I want to get this via java SDKs